# JavaScript split string into json

Tags: javascript, string, split

I would like to split the string into JSON. Below is some example:

```
Mon, Fri 2:30 pm - 8 pm / Tues 15 am - 2 pm / Weds 1:15 pm - 3:15 am /....

Mon, Weds - Thurs, Sat 7:15 pm - 3:30 am / Tues 4:45 pm - 5 pm / Fri 8:25 am - 9:30 pm / ...

Mon, Weds - Sun 7:15 pm - 3:30 am

Mon - Sun 7:15 pm - 3:30 am
```

I hope I can get the JSON from each line:

```
[
    {
        day: Mon,
        openning_time: 7:15 pm
        closing_time: 3:30 am
    },
    ....
]
```

I had tried many methods but still cannot make it. Hope can get some idea

Comment: First, create a regex for each data item you want to convert to a JSON object, then parse each data item and set the fields (day, opening_time, closing_time) . It seems like your delimeter might be the / (forward backslash).

Comment: it's a very vague question that requires a very deep analisys of that text to determine the clear encoding rules. It's not an easy task to craft those regex. The logic to dump those matches in an object are easy but you should really make your mind very clear on the rules behind those texts. The complicated part is how to split a line containing several timespans and how to detect several days in a given interval to split in different objects belonging to each day opening/closing

Comment: yes, it is very hard to craft regex. The only idea that I have is to do it manually but it wastes a lot of time

Comment: what result do yopu expect? an array for each line? what have you tried?

Comment: I hope i can get the JSON from each line. I have tried 1) split into array and do the regex 2) do the regex direct to the string 3) use condition function and rewrite the string

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split each input string into fields.

Once this is complete we'll use a regular expression to parse each field into day, opening time and closing time using [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

We'd also create a `splitDays()` function to turn a day range like `Mon, Weds - Thurs` into an array of days like `[Mon,Weds,Thurs]`, this will allow us to create the final result.

```js
function splitDays(days) {
    return days.split(',').flatMap(splitDayRange);  
}

function splitDayRange(range) {
    const days = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Weds', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
    const [startIndex, endIndex] = range.trim().split(/\s*\-\s*/).map(day => days.findIndex(d => d === day));
    return days.filter((day, idx, arr) => { 
        return (idx >= startIndex) && (idx <= (endIndex || startIndex));
    });
}

function parseInput(input) {
    const parseRegEx = /([a-z\s\,\-]*)(\d+:?\d* (?:am|pm))\s*\-\s*(\d+:?\d*\s*(am|pm))/i
    return input.split(/\s*\/\s*/).flatMap(field => { 
        const [, days, opening_time, closing_time ] = field.match(parseRegEx);
        return splitDays(days).map(day => { 
            return { day, opening_time, closing_time };
        })
    });
}

let inputs = [
    'Mon, Fri 2:30 pm - 8 pm / Tues 15 am - 2 pm / Weds 1:15 pm - 3:15 am',
    'Mon, Weds - Thurs, Sat 7:15 pm - 3:30 am / Tues 4:45 pm - 5 pm / Fri 8:25 am - 9:30 pm',
    'Mon, Weds - Sun 7:15 pm - 3:30 am',
    'Mon - Sun 7:15 pm - 3:30 am'
]

for(let input of inputs) {
    console.log('Input:');
    console.log(input);
    console.log('Output:');
    console.log(parseInput(input));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not a best performance solution but you can get the idea.
The last part is missing because I'm not sure of the day notation so I leave that to you.
Basically what you have to implement is another flatmap that splits the day string in an array of days

```js
const stringToParse = 
`Mon, Fri 2:30 pm - 8 pm / Tues 15 am - 2 pm / Weds 1:15 pm - 3:15 am
Mon, Weds - Thurs, Sat 7:15 pm - 3:30 am / Tues 4:45 pm - 5 pm / Fri 8:25 am - 9:30 pm
Mon, Weds - Sun 7:15 pm - 3:30 am
Mon - Sun 7:15 pm - 3:30 am`;

const daysArray = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Weds', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

const json = stringToParse.split('\n')
.flatMap(line => line.split('/').map(s => s.trim()))
.map(s => {
  const [closingType, closing, _,openingType, opening, ...days] = s.split(' ').reverse()
  return {
    days: days.reverse().join(' '),
    openning_time: `${opening} ${openingType}`,
    closing_time: `${closing} ${closingType}`
  }
})

console.log(json)
```